# Trying to create array with 3 coulms by using a lsi, but can figure out how to add a row

Tags: python

I have created a list as follows

```
chart=[ [1], [2], [3] ]
```

when I print it, i get
`[ [1], [2], [3] ]`

now I try to add another row

```
chart.append([ [4],[5],[6]] )
[[1], [2], [3], [[4], [5], [6]]]
```

It added another row not column,
How can I get it so if I would get

```
[ [1,4], [2, 5], [3,6]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straightforwardly:

Note: `chart.append(...)` in the question means that the initial list is expected to be **modified**

```
chart = [[1], [2], [3]]
new_cols = [[4], [5], [6]]
for i, lst in enumerate(chart):
    chart[i] += new_cols[i]

print(chart)   # [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
a = [ [1], [2], [3] ]
b = [ [4],[5],[6]]

print( [i + j for i, j in zip(a, b)] )
```

Output:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the results for your above `chart` list `[[1], [2], [3], [[4], [5], [6]]]`

`out = []
    for i in range(len(chart)-1):
        a = chart[i]
        a.append(chart[-1][i][0])
        out.append(a)
    print(out)`